# Почему нет доступа к конструктору

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Есть такой код:

```
class a
{
    protected a(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
    public string s;   
}
class b : a
{
    public b(string s)  : base(s)
    { }
    public a RetObj()
    {
        return new a("jk"); //не работает
    }
}
```

Почему не создается объект в методе `RetObj()` ведь доступ к конструктору из класса b открыт для этого же класа. При этом выдается ошибка `Ошибка   1   a не содержит конструктор, который принимает 1 аргументов` Подскажите, что тут не так ?? Можно конечно сделать в этом методе `return this;` но хотелось бы понять почему нельзя создать объект класса а.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Это ограничение стандарта языка. В C# 1 то, о чём вы говорите, было возможно.

В более новых версиях языка (начиная с C# 2) действует следующее правило:

1. Вы можете обращаться к **статическим** защищённым полям, свойствам и методам из дочернего класса без ограничений.
2. Вы можете обращаться к **нестатическим** защищённым полям, свойствам и методам из дочернего класса **только** через *какой-то* (любой) объект этого самого дочернего класса. Причём имеется в виду не динамический (runtime-), а статический (compile time) тип объекта.

Конструктор причисляется к группе, покрываемой вторым случаем.

**Мотивация:**

Откуда взялось такое дополнительное требование для instance-методов? А вот откуда. Допустим, что такого требования не было бы. Тогда всю защиту, накладываемую protected, было бы очень легко обойти. Действительно, пусть у нас есть такой класс:

```
class B
{
    protected int X = 0;
}
```

Кто угодно мог бы обойти защиту и изменить `X` таким образом:

```
class Attacker : B
{
    static public void ModifyX(B b, int value)
    {
        b.X = value;
    }
}
```

(Этот приём известен как паттерн «Паблик Морозов».)

Правило 2 запрещает такие трюки. С этим правилом, автор класса `Attacker` может «испортить» только объекты *своего* класса, но не чужой объект.

Поскольку на защите через атрибуты контроля доступности наподобие private/protected базируется безопасность библиотеки .NET, подобный метод «обхода» защиты был бы серьёзной дырой. Фактически, подобные дыры были найдены в коде .NET framework, так что это ограничение их ликвидирует.

---

<sub>Ответ основан на статье [*Many Questions: Protected Constructors*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/peterhal/many-questions-protected-constructors) из блогов MSDN.</sub>

Comment: `static class` не может указывать базовый.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Спасибо! Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо. Очень популярно !! Хотел у Вас только уточнить по второму правилу. Я же ведь могу в методе производного класса использовать переменные базового класса без ссылки на базовый класс. Например переменная `protected int x = 60` в базовом может быть изменена в методе производного просто `x = 90`. И только что в msdn  обнаружил, что не через ЛЮБОЙ объект, а только через производный. Хотя может я не правильно что-то понял https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bcd5672a.aspx в самом первом примере так расписано

Comment: @polyakov_s: Можете потому, что неявно `x = 90` на самом деле есть `this.x = 90`, а `this` — экземпляр нужного класса. Если бы вы написали `Base b = this; b.x = 90;`, это бы не скомпилировалось.

Comment: Хотелось бы отметить, что хотя `атрибуты контроля доступности` и являются частью механизма безопасности, по большей части служат другой цели - инкапсуляции. А дыр и без этого хватает - тот же `System.Reflection`. В данном случае тоже, думаю, проблема больше с точки зрения инкапсуляции.

Comment: @pkuderov: рефлексия не является дырой, так как доступна только для кода с [`ReflectionPermission`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).